# Backbone.js: Save's success function simply does not work

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to get the most basic thing running in Backbone.js but somehow fail. The code I've produced for saving a **url** model into the server.

```
urlToAdd.set({url: urlBody.value, tags:tagsToAdd});
                urlToAdd.save({
                    success:function(){
                        console.log('it works');
                    }
                });
```

It **successfully** sends the data to my php page however I can not get **success**event to work. Where am I doing wrong? I've carefully observed and couldn't find anything.

Here is my model definition: (Unfortunately since I am backbone noob I've applied this by checking a tutorial and I have no idea if the codes in **url** function are necessary

```
var URLWithTags=Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize:function(){
                console.log('URL object has been initialized');
            },
            defaults:{
                url:'not defined',
                tags:[]
            },
            validate:function(attributes){
            //console.log(attributes.tags[0].length);
                /*if(attributes.tags[0].length<1)
                    return "You should create at least one tag";*/
            },
            urlRoot:'/URLTags/manage.php',
            url:function(){
                var base = this.urlRoot || (this.collection && this.collection.url) || "/";
                console.log("Base has been produced");
                if(this.isNew())
                    return base;

                return base+"?id="+encodeURIComponent(this.id);
            },
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757555/how-do-i-trigger-the-success-callback-on-a-model-save

Comment: @Gohn67 Thanks for the comment. Mine is different because im calling the **model's** save function

Answer (score 2):

Save should be the second argument in an object when you call the save function.
please people read the doc , or the source it is well commented ,short and easy to read.

```
urlToAdd.save(null,{success:function(){console.log('it works')}});
```

according to the doc :

```
savemodel.save([attributes], [options]) ;
```

so :

```
urlToAdd.save({},{success:successCallback , error:errorCallback});
```

**EDIT**

Exemple :

```
    var Car,yukon,$target ;
    Object.prototype.toString = function(){
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    };

    Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:"/echo/json"
    });
    yukon= new Car({"color":"red","brand":"GM"});
    $target = $("#target");

    $target.append("describe yukon :",yukon.toString(),"<br/>");

    yukon.save({},
{
success:function(o){$target.append("save success <br/>",o.toString())},
error:function(e){$target.append("error",e)}
}
);
```

where $target is a jquery object representing a div with the id of target.

Comment: I will update the code the way you suggested but I think I've tried before and did not work

Comment: Did not work. `urlToAdd.set({url: urlBody.value, tags:tagsToAdd});
    urlToAdd.save(null,
    {
     success:function()
     {
      console.log('it works')
     }
    });` added an additional `}` because it was giving a syntax error

Comment: yep i forgot a } , create an error function , too in case your save action fails :

Comment: `urlToAdd.set({url: urlBody.value, tags:tagsToAdd});
    urlToAdd.save(null,
    {
     success:function()
     {
      console.log('it works')
     }

    },
    {
          error:function()
     {
      console.log('it does not work');
     }
    });` does nothing. Sorry if I'm asking too much but it really prints nothing while my server side php saves the data to database

Comment: well , we need the rest of the model definition. Be sure to configure Backbone.sync too if your script is not a restfull api.

Comment: I've edited the question and I do not know how to configure the sync, kinda newbie so..

Comment: I set up a small exemple here : http://jsfiddle.net/camus/rz8WT/ , and check your javascript console for any errors.

Comment: will it work if I applied to my example, in here you do not send any data to php thats why I'm asking

Comment: well the problem is first do you get errors in the console when you save your model , yes or, no, second , is your php script a restfull api or not , you did not answer that.

Comment: In my php I've basically check for the server's request and if it is a post I've save the url to my database, if that's what you mean. Sorry if I got it wrong

Comment: you did not answer me , do you get errors in the browser console or not ?

Comment: I do not and it succesfully saves the url to database

Comment: and what is the php script response ?

Comment: `PHP works
I have received a .save() method from backbone
ab.com
{"Info":"Successfully placed"}` is my response. Using echo to print them

Comment: are you sure you have jQuery and underscore libraries before Backbone ? and did you empty your browser cache to reload the script ,etc ? because there is no reason why it would not work ? by the way , the success and error function must be in the same object, not in 2 separate objects .