# Backbone model.save() not hitting success/error callback?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple `Backbone` model:

```
define(function(require) {

  var Backbone = require('backbone');

  var SessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://stormy-ravine-2549.herokuapp.com/login',
    parse: function(data) {
      debugger;
    }
  });

  return SessionModel;
});
```

Here is my code where I am saving the model:

```
    var sessionModel = new SessionModel();
      sessionModel.set('username', $('#email').val());
      sessionModel.set('password', $('#password').val());
      sessionModel.save({
        success: function() {
          debugger;
        },
        error: function() {
          debugger;
        }
     });
```

I get a `200` response from the server with a `json` body of `{"msg": "success"}`.  I hit the `parse` method in the `model`, but neither one of my callback functions get hit.  Also, I am running my `Chrome` browser with `CORS` disabled.  Doesn't either the `success` or `error`callback have to be hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling backbone to only change the properties `success` and `error`. The **second** parameter is for options.

See [Backbone model.save() not calling either error or success callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322182/backbone-model-save-not-calling-either-error-or-success-callbacks?rq=1) and also http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

> save accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash