# Model save backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm saving a model on a online db Parse.com. The save function works perfectly but the callback function inside save are not called.

```
this.utente.save( {
                  success: function (persona) {//never called
                      console.log("modello salvato nel db");
                    console.log(persona);

                  },

                  error: function (data){//never called

                      console.log(data)
                  }


                });
```

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322182/backbone-model-save-not-calling-either-error-or-success-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

[`Backbone.Model#save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) takes options in the *second* argument:

> **save** `model.save([attributes], [options])`
>
> Save a model to your database (or alternative persistence layer), by delegating to *Backbone.sync*.

If you want to call `save` without any particular attributes and you want to supply `options`, say:

```
model.save(null, { ... })
```

You probably want to say:

```
this.utente.save(null, {
    success: function (persona) { ... },
    error: function (data) { ... }
});
```