# Backbone Error Callback with Rails 4 Controller Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a backbone app that I have integrated into my rails app. I am trying to pass my validation errors back to a Backbone Model on creation but it's not making it all the way back to Backbone.

Here's my model:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/models/source.js.coffee
class MyApp.Models.Source extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/api/sources'
```

And my rails controller:

```
# app/controller/api/sources_controller.rb
class Api::SourcesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @source = Source.new source_params

    if @source.save
      respond_with @source
    else
      render json: { error: @source.error.messages }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def source_params
    params.require(:source).permit(:feed_id, :source, :term)
  end
end
```

And finally the code that attempts to create my model:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/views/new_source.js.coffee
class MyApp.Views.SourceForm extends Backbone.View
  events: ->
    'submit .new_source': 'createSource'

  createSource: ->
    @source = new Juicer.Models.Source $(event.target).serializeHash()
    @source.save
      success: =>
        console.log 'ya'
      error: =>
        console.log 'boo'
```

When I actually run this code however, it never makes it all the way back to this backbone callback, instead I get this error in the console:

[image: (422 (Unprocessable Entity)]

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/sources 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

I've dug around a bit in the Backbone source but I can't figure out why this isn't making it through. It seems to be stuck at the jQuery .ajax method, which should be triggering the error callback, but instead seems to be breaking.

I'm using Backbone v1.1.1 and jQuery v1.11.1 and Rails 4.1.5

Comment: @muistooshort I am purposefully wanting it to fail in this case, I want source.save to return false. It works fine if I pass in proper parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to hit the error callback if I pass in null as the first argument to save per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322182/backbone-model-save-not-calling-either-error-or-success-callbacks) SO post

Like so:

```
createSource: ->
  @source = new Juicer.Models.Source $(event.target).serializeHash()
  @source.save null,
    success: =>
      console.log 'ya'
    error: =>
      console.log 'boo'
```