# Access `this` from callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, callback

Similar question was already asked here [How do I trigger the success callback on a model.save()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757555/how-do-i-trigger-the-success-callback-on-a-model-save), but still no answer how to trigger events from callbacks.

So here is `success` callback in my code, in which I want to call `addOne` event to render saved Comment. Everything works well except `this.addOne(receivedItem);` - I can't use `this` in callback to trigger this event. Everywhere else - I can.

How to solve this problem?

```
CommentsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    addOne: function (item) {
        var commentView = new CommentView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(commentView.render().el);
    },
    addNewComment: function (event) {
        var item = {
            post_id: this.$('#post_id').val(),
            text: this.$('#text').val()
        };
        var commentItem = new CommentItem();
        commentItem.save({'model':item}, { 
            success: function(receivedItem, response) {
                this.addOne(receivedItem); // Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'addOne'.
            }
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That happens because the success callback has a different scope, and `this` does not point to your view.
To quickly solve this, just make a reference to `this` and use it instead:

```
var self = this;
commentItem.save({'model':item}, { 
    success: function(receivedItem, response) {
        self.addOne(receivedItem); // works
    }
});
```

or you can use underscore's [`bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) method to bind a different context to a function :

```
success : _.bind(function(receivedItem, response) {
    this.addOne(receivedItem); 
}, this)
```

Comment: You are genius man! It works! And it will be useful for others - I spent hours to solve this (I'm not so good in javascript yet) :)

Comment: @MdaG are you referring to underscore's `bind` method?

Comment: No, I mean how can sending "this" as an additional parameter make it work? I have a knowledge gap here as I've seen it used in other code as well.

Comment: @MdaG That's what underscore's bind function does. It takes 2 arguments : a function and an object, and returns a new function with the specified object as scope. I's similar to the standard `bind` method of functions in es5 : `var getFoo = function (){return this.foo;}.bind({foo:'bar'})`. you should probably read the docs to clear that gap :)

Comment: Read the docs. :) Understand bind (or do I?), but I meant your first example where you send 'this' as a third parameter to save. According to the docs it only takes two arguments. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

Comment: @MdaG I'm sorry that I didn't understand what you were saying before. You are right: `model.save` only takes 2 arguments. I really can't remember how or why the third argument got in that function call (since this answer dates a while back). It is unnecessary and misleading and I apologize for that. Anyway, the thing is that the context is preserved by using a reference to `this` in the `self` variable. Updated the answer too. thx

Answer (score 0):

This could be a late answer. but would help somebody who is looking for it. This is accessing 'this' keyword from a settimeout callback

```
CommentsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
...
    addOne: function (item) {
        // DO Stuff
    },
    addNewComment: _.bind(function (event) {
        setTimeout(_.bind(function(){ 
            this.addOne(/*receivedItem*/);
        }, this), 1000);
    }, this)
});
```